NATS subject wildcard
I want to use wildcard at start of NATS subject while subscribing to NATS topic e.g. "*.events.east.india" and it should receive event for subject "Kolkata-Manipur.events.east.india" and "Kohima-Shilong.events.east.india". As per NATS document we can use wildcard * at start of the subject but in my usecase its not working. Can someone help me with that. Following line of code I am using to subscribe to NATS message
        var jsoptions = NATS.Client.JetStream.JetStreamOptions.DefaultJsOptions;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(domainName))
        {
            jsoptions = NATS.Client.JetStream.JetStreamOptions.Builder()
                .WithDomain(domainName)
                .Build();
        }

        var js = connection?.CreateJetStreamContext(jsoptions);


       var sub = js?.PushSubscribeAsync("*.events.east.india", OnReceiveMessage, true);

I have tried to use > wildcard at start of subject but still its not working
